# How to enable auto close brackets in WinEdt?

Tags: winedt

Title.

I have read the "docs" for it however it only mentions Active Strings as a way (`ALT` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`) which works but it is manual. I would like it to auto complete `}` as soon as I type `{`. Is such a thing possible ?

---

I am also looking for a way to enable snippets/templates as in if I type `mbb` then it expands into `\mathbb{@cursor here}`. I have found [FasTeX](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/%7Efastex/fastex.html) for it which looks similar to what I want but is it customizable easily ? Is there a native way to do it without plugins ?

Comment: I personally have a  shortcut `Alt+[` which produces a pair `[ ]`  and the cursor in-between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open in the options interface the ActiveStrings.ini script

[image]

Then search for

```
STRING="{"
  ENABLED=0 
  MACRO="[Ins('}');CharLeft;]"
  DBL_CLICK_ENABLED=1
  DBL_CLICK_MACRO="[MatchDelimiter(1,1,1);]"
```

change that to `ENABLED=1` and then load the script.

Comment: works! Thank you.