# How to enable brackets "()", "[]" and "{}" autocompletion in WinEdt editor?

Tags: brackets, winedt

I want brackets auto-completion in `LaTeX`. For example, when I typed `(`, I want `)` appear automatically. There was a [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640646/how-to-enable-auto-close-brackets-in-winedt) very similar, and I tried like [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) answered: go to the **ActiveStrings.ini** script and revise `ENABLED=0` to `ENABLED=1`. See below

```
STRING="{"
  ENABLED=1
  MACRO="[Ins('}');CharLeft;]"
  DBL_CLICK_ENABLED=1
  DBL_CLICK_MACRO="[MatchDelimiter(1,1,1);]"
```

However, it did not work for me. Can it be dealt with simple customization in WinEdt or it requires some `LaTeX` macro setup? In `TeXstudio`, there is no problem with brackets auto-completion according to my use experience.

Comment: did you load the script after the change?

Comment: Sorry, I did not, in the thought that save the script would be fine. The word `**load**` means that you have to click the `**Load Current Script**` botton on the `Optioins Interface`, which is a little small -__-#. The other type of brackets `()`, `[]` can be done in this way too. Thank you @UlrikeFischer.